# I have a button in a listview and when clicked all its instances are being clicked

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a listview containing a button and a textview the textview is being clicked normally; but I have a method for the button click, and when the button is clicked it should change the background image, so by clicking a button all the instances of the button are changing the background image, so I click on fiew buttons in the listview and I scroll down and I see that several button have their background image changed than the place of the buttons with the changed background changes while scrolling the listview up again;
how can I fix that?

**the code of the content of my listview:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_rating" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
     android:onClick="myClickHandler"/>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/fsinlistview"

 />
</LinearLayout>
```

**the code of my button click is:**

```
public void myClickHandler(View v) 
     {


    Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.bt_rating);     
    button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);


     }
```

Comment: What does the code for the `myClickHandler` method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying the background resource for *all* buttons with the `R.id.bt_rating` id, where as you'd like to modify the button that was *clicked*.

You already have a reference to that - it's the `View` that is passed in.

Change your code to:

```
public void myClickHandler(View v) 
{   
    v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
}
```

Of course, since you're using a list view, once you scroll through/past this, it won't persist state. What you should be doing is:

1. updating the data backing your adapter
2. call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter
3. handle the button on/off state display in the adapters `getView`

Comment: when I called v.setbackgroundRessource... I had the same result several buttons where called..

Comment: When you say 'several', do you mean all on the screen at once, or do they only show up after scrolling?

Comment: If you're using a `SimpleAdapter` or an `ArrayAdapter` you'll have to learn how to implement your own `BaseAdapter`. If you're already using a custom adapter, then your `getView` method is not updating the supplied `convertView`.

Comment: What's happening is that you're changing the state of the button, then the view scrolls off the screen, gets 'recycled'/reused and the button is still in the same state as it was when it went off the screen - the adapter is only updating some other part of the row.

Comment: I am using a simple cursor adapter

Comment: You'll need to either extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` to modify the view in the `getView` method, or (preferably) implement a [`ViewBinder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html).

Comment: can you give me an example of the viewbinder plz been trying to do it for hours and it's not working...thanks.

Comment: There are [many](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193727/1217087) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15314041/1217087) [available](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10355822/1217087). If you still can't get it working, you should open a new question with the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: I've already done that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956876/how-to-bind-a-checkbox-to-a-listview   but no one replied will see ur examples now thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Put the setOnclickListener in your getView method of your adapter