# how to bind a checkbox to a listview

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

I have a listview containing on each row a textview with a checkbox, so when the checkbox is checked and we scroll down through the listview the checkbox instance will be taken from a place to another (reused..) and I have several checked checkboxes how to fix that I tried to bind the checkbox to the listview but that didn't work my code is:

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rating,cu,new String[]{"Title","Favorites"}, new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.bt_rating},CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        listv.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
               /** Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view */
               public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
                   if(view.getId() == R.id.bt_rating){

                      ((CheckBox)view).setChecked(Boolean.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Favorites"))));
                      ((CheckBox)view).setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
                       return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
                   }
                   return false;
               }
            });


 OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                 buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);
            }
        };
```

My xml code of the content of the row of my listview is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/bt_rating"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
 android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/fsinlistview"

 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection

Comment: didn't find what I need there sadly... will continue my search.. thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `OnCheckedChangedListener` is the problem here. If you look at your code, see that *every* checkbox is getting a reference to the *same* listener. So when you check one box, you're setting every other box as checked too - and you're not updating your backing data, either.

Your `OnCheckedChangedListener` should not be updating the view state of the checkbox - the callback is fired because the state has already changed.

So you need to do the following steps when a user checks the checkbox:

1. Figure out which item was checked, and how that corresponds to your data
2. Update your data to suit the new checked/unchecked state
3. Notify your adapter of a data change/update your cursor

You could do this something like the following, tagging the view with the ID of the row it represents:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.bt_rating){
        view.setTag(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SomeDBContract.ID)));
        ((CheckBox)view).setChecked(Boolean.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Favorites"))));
        ((CheckBox)view).setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
        return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, in your listener you can update your database according to that ID:

```
CheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
             int rowId = (int) buttonView.getTag();
             // Handle updating the database as per normal
             updateSomeDbRowAsChecked(rowId, isChecked);
        }
    };
```

Finally, you'll need to update your cursor adapter with a new cursor once the database row is updated:

```
 myAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
```

You'll have to adjust all of this to suit your code, but it should give you an idea of one way you can approach this problem.

Comment: ok will fix that but also my viewbinder is not getting called because I placed a log.d inside it and it's not being called..

Comment: also the content of the listener was just added directly to check the result, what I need to do is to add the changes to my database; but why the viewbinder isn't getting called?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, sorry - the code to setup the view binder looks correct.

Comment: yes I had errors in the adapter I didn't add the bt_rating in it that's why now it's accessing the binder but still getting incorrect results will check the reason later if God wills.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In any Listview, the view are reused. As you scroll through the list, those that scroll up and off screen are recycled and used with newer information as it comes in below.

You need to keep track of your checkboxes with a sparse array.  Mark the index in the array as cherked/unchecked as the user touches each.  You then set the state of the checkbox based on the value in the array.

Here is some example code from an an older app, that does both a "select all" checkboxes as well as manages the entire list of those checked and unchecked. It was for a classroom attendance app I wrote, so it was much easier for a teacher to select "ALL" being in class and then unselect those that weren't present.

I have two checkboxes in this listview, and two sparse arrays, itemCheckedHere and itemCheckedLate (whether a student is in class, or was late).

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Cursor c;
    private Context context;
    private Long classnum;
    private gradeBookDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    public static final int LATE=2;
    public static final int ATTEND=1;
    int idxCol;
    int idx;

    // itemChecked will store the position of the checked items.

    public MyDataAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, Long mRowId) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;
        mDbHelper = new gradeBookDbAdapter(context);
        mDbHelper.open();
        classnum = mRowId;
        c.moveToFirst();



    }
    public class ViewHolder{
        public TextView text;
        public TextView text2;
        public ImageView image;
        public CheckBox here;
        public CheckBox late;
    }


    public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Bitmap bm;
        ImageView studentPhoto;
        View vi=inView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (inView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_attendance, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.stuname);
            holder.text2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.stuIndex);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.here=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.attend);
            holder.late=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.late);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
           holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


        c.moveToPosition(pos);
        int index = c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_NAME);
        String name = c.getString(index);
        holder.text.setText(name);
        index = c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID); 
        String Index = c.getString(index);
        holder.text2.setText(Index);

        bm = gradeBookDbAdapter.getStudentPhoto(name);
        if (bm != null) {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);  
        }           
        else {
            // use icon image
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.person_icon);
        }


        // pull out existing attend/late fields and set accordingly
        int attend = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_ATTEND));
        if(attend==1){
           holder.here.setChecked(true);
           itemCheckedHere.set(pos, true);
        }
        //else {
        //   holder.here.setChecked(false);
        //   itemCheckedHere.set(pos, false);
        //}

        int late = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_LATE));
        if (late==1){
           holder.late.setChecked(true);
           itemCheckedLate.set(pos, true);
        }
        //else {
        //  holder.late.setChecked(false);
        //    itemCheckedLate.set(pos, false);
        //}


        if (selectAllTouched) {
            if(selectAll){
                holder.here.setChecked(true);
                itemCheckedHere.set(pos, true);
                int who= new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                mDbHelper.updateAttend(who, classnum, ATTEND, 1, attendDate );
            }
            else{
                holder.here.setChecked(false);
                itemCheckedHere.set(pos, false);
                int who = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                mDbHelper.updateAttend(who, classnum, ATTEND, 0, attendDate );
            }
        }


        holder.here.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.attend);

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemCheckedHere.set(pos, true); 
                    int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                    mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, ATTEND, 1, attendDate ); 
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemCheckedHere.set(pos, false);
                    int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                    mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, ATTEND, 0, attendDate );
                }
            }
        });
        holder.late.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.late);

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                   itemCheckedLate.set(pos, true);
                   int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                   mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, LATE, 1, attendDate );
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                   itemCheckedLate.set(pos, false);
                   int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                   mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, LATE, 0, attendDate );
                }
            }
        });


        holder.here.setChecked(itemCheckedHere.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
        holder.late.setChecked(itemCheckedLate.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
        // CheckBox in ListView
        // according to their original
        // position and CheckBox never
        // loss his State when you
        // Scroll the List Items.

        return vi;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: thank you very much martin but this code is different from mine will see it if I ran out of solutions :)

Comment: yes, it different from yours. My intent was not to write your code for you but rather provide an example of how to deal with checkboxes in a listview.  If you're looking for plug-n-play code that you can simply drop into your project, I need to first give you my paypal account into which you can pay me money for my efforts.