# Android SimpleCursorAdapter setViewBinder vs bindView

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I'm really confused with these two. I need to bind a checkbox to my listview. I can't do it in bindview, since the cursors position gets all mixed up. and then i saw this one [how to bind a checkbox to a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956876/how-to-bind-a-checkbox-to-a-listview) . and was really confused between the two.

Comment: you can use `bindView` after all `bindView` calls `ViewBinder` if set, see the sources [here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java#135), note line 145

Comment: So the two work together? and function as one?

Comment: sorry i dont get you... just override `bindView`, call the super and do your stuff witch the checkbox here

Comment: Thanks, i think i got it now. :D

Comment: if not sure what is `Cursor` param in `bindView` call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow`